# Kicad: error 40 when exporting BOM using Python

Tags: python, kicad

From EESchema I’m trying the various BOM export scripts to find which one is better for my needs. Most of them fails with the following error, though:

```
Run command:
python "/usr/share/kicad/plugins/bom_html_with_advanced_grouping.py" "/home/andrea/myboard.xml" "/home/andrea/myboard"

Command error. Return code -1
Error messages:
execvp(python, /usr/share/kicad/plugins/bom_html_with_advanced_grouping.py, /home/andrea/myboard.xml, /home/andrea/myboard) failed with error 40!
```

I cannot understand what is "error 40".
Here the list of the scripts that fail:

```
bom_html_with_advanced_grouping.py
bom_html_grouped_by_value.py
bom_sorted_by_ref.py
bom_csv_sorted_by_ref.py
bom_csv_grouped_by_value_with_fp
bom_csv_grouped_by_value.py
```

They all seem to use Python, so I guess there's something wrong with it. But in my system I have a working `python2` and `python3` and I also checked the built-in Kicad's python is working (i.e. from Pcbnew I can successfully open Tools > Scripting Console). So I don't think this is the problem (otherwise Kicad would have told if it hadn't found the needed dependencies).

I also tried to create alias for `python` to `python2` or `python3` but nothing has changed.

Furthermore I don't understand if "Error 40" comes from Kicad, Python or execvp.

Kicad information:

```
Application: Eeschema
Version: 5.1.9-73d0e3b20d~88~ubuntu20.04.1, release build
Libraries:
    wxWidgets 3.0.4
    libcurl/7.68.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1f zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.7 libidn2/2.2.0 libpsl/0.21.0 (+libidn2/2.2.0) libssh/0.9.3/openssl/zlib nghttp2/1.40.0 librtmp/2.3
Platform: Linux 5.4.0-65-generic x86_64, 64 bit, Little endian, wxGTK
Build Info:
    wxWidgets: 3.0.4 (wchar_t,wx containers,compatible with 2.8) GTK+ 3.24
    Boost: 1.71.0
    OpenCASCADE Community Edition: 6.9.1
    Curl: 7.68.0
    Compiler: GCC 9.3.0 with C++ ABI 1013

Build settings:
    USE_WX_GRAPHICS_CONTEXT=OFF
    USE_WX_OVERLAY=ON
    KICAD_SCRIPTING=ON
    KICAD_SCRIPTING_MODULES=ON
    KICAD_SCRIPTING_PYTHON3=ON
    KICAD_SCRIPTING_WXPYTHON=ON
    KICAD_SCRIPTING_WXPYTHON_PHOENIX=ON
    KICAD_SCRIPTING_ACTION_MENU=ON
    BUILD_GITHUB_PLUGIN=ON
    KICAD_USE_OCE=ON
    KICAD_USE_OCC=OFF
    KICAD_SPICE=ON
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not sure about a BOM script, to get diagnostics you can run them from the command line. There is nothing special about the way KiCad invokes them.